# jqGrid Link Display Text

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

How do I set the display text on a link column in jqGrid.  I want the text in every column to just say "View" with the link containing the specific Id.  Here is what I currently have, but the Id get displayed in the column instead of the text "View".  I was hoping to do it without passing the link html in the json returned data.

```
{ name: 'myId', index: 'View', edittype: 'select', formatter: 'showlink', formatoptions: {  baseLinkUrl: 'Consumer/Details', idName: 'myId'} }
```

My json object getting return looks like this:

```
select new
                                   {
                                       myId = obj.myId.ToString(),
                                       Date = String.Format("{0:d}", obj.Date),
                                       Description = obj.Description,
                                       View = "View"
                                   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correct understand your question you can just use the following simple custom formatter instead of 'showlink' predefined formatter:

```
formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    return '<a href="Consumer/Details?myId=' + opts.rowId + '">View</a>';
}
```

If you need to include some additional information in the URL of `href` you can use properties of the `rowObject` (`rowObject.Date`, `rowObject.Description`) or replace `opts.rowId` to the `cellvalue` or `rowObject.myId`.

You should additionally verify whether the property `edittype: 'select'` which you use is correct for the column. It looks like Cut&Paste error, especially because you don't use `editable: true` property.

Comment: shouldn't be 'function formatter' instead of 'formatter: function'? I am new to javascript, just found that 'function formatter' works for me.

Comment: @pstar: No. 'formatter' is the property name. it can be a function. One can define anonymous function as the property value. So you should just try the code from the answer and place the `formatter` property in the column where you use currently `formatter: 'showlink'`.